# Standards for double quoted shell strings

Tags: shell, string, posix

Are there any standards regarding double quoted shell strings?
I'd like to know details such as in what exact contexts is `$` supposed to be interpreted literally, what exact patterns are `$` variables supposed to match, and if anything other than `$variables`, `${variables}`, `backtick blocks`, and `$(process substitution blocks)` is supposed to be handled specially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify in *what shell* you are interested. The answer is based on the assumption that you are asking about [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)). When `man bash` is not enough:

- The home of Bash is at https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashtop.html; there you will find the [Reference Manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html).
- For a formal definition of the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell, see [*The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, 2016 Edition); select the volume *Shell & Utilities*.